# Sending to channel doesn't happen if select has default

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I am working on a personal project that will run on a Raspberry Pi with some sensors attached to it.

The function that read from the sensors and the function that handle the socket connection are executed in different goroutines, so, in order to send data on the socket when they are read from the sensors, I create a `chan []byte` in the main function and pass it to the goroutines.

My problem came out here: if I do multiple writes in a row, only the first data arrives to the client, but the others don't. But if I put a little `time.Sleep` in the sender function, all the data arrives correctly to the client.

Anyway, that's a simplified version of this little program :

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const socketName string = "./test_socket"

// create to the socket and launch the accept client routine
func launchServerUDS(ch chan []byte) {
    if err := os.RemoveAll(socketName); err != nil {
        return
    }
    l, err := net.Listen("unix", socketName)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    go acceptConnectionRoutine(l, ch)
}

// accept incoming connection on the socket and
// 1) launch the routine to handle commands from the client
// 2) launch the routine to send data when the server reads from the sensors
func acceptConnectionRoutine(l net.Listener, ch chan []byte) {
    defer l.Close()
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        go commandsHandlerRoutine(conn, ch)
        go autoSendRoutine(conn, ch)

    }
}

// routine that sends data to the client
func autoSendRoutine(c net.Conn, ch chan []byte) {
    for {
        data := <-ch
        if string(data) == "exit" {
            return
        }
        c.Write(data)
    }
}

// handle client connection and calls functions to execute commands
func commandsHandlerRoutine(c net.Conn, ch chan []byte) {
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        n, err := c.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            ch <- []byte("exit")
            break
        }
        // now, for sake of simplicity , only echo commands back to the client
        _, err = c.Write(buf[:n])
        if err != nil {
            ch <- []byte("exit")
            break
        }
    }
}

// write on the channel to the autosend routine so the data are written on the socket
func sendDataToClient(data []byte, ch chan []byte) {
    select {
    case ch <- data:
        // if i put a little sleep here, no problems
        // i i remove the sleep, only data1 is sent to the client
        // time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    default:
    }
}

func dummyReadDataRoutine(ch chan []byte) {
    for {
        // read data from the sensors every 5 seconds
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        // read first data and send it
        sendDataToClient([]byte("dummy data1\n"), ch)
        // read second data and send it
        sendDataToClient([]byte("dummy data2\n"), ch)
        // read third data and send it
        sendDataToClient([]byte("dummy data3\n"), ch)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan []byte)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)
    go dummyReadDataRoutine(ch)
    go launchServerUDS(ch)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I don't think it's correct to use a sleep to synchronize writes. How do I fix this while keeping the functions running on a different different goroutines.

Comment: You likely haven't found anything searching, becasue you have a bunch of unrelated issues. Always try to simplify _as much as possible_ to create your [mre], because none of this has anything to do with unix sockets. You have goroutines calling goroutines calling goroutines for no reason. Your `WaitGroup` does nothing because no goroutine calls `Done()` (nor could they, because it's not in their scope). Sending data over a channel is in a separate function unnecessarily, with a `default` case in your select for no discernible reason.

Comment: The channel is unbuffered, and you write to the channel with a select and a default that does nothing. To fix your code you should add buffering to the channel and remove the select. Then simply write data to the channel.

Comment: @JimB hi, thanks for the suggestions,this example is simplified for me because my program is bigger than this and i've added the waitgroup here only to launch the routines, so i didn't put any wg.Done() for this reason, anyway , thanks a lot fo your suggestions

Comment: @chmike i will try your solution and edit my question , thanks to you too

Comment: @Leonardo, leaving nonsensical code like that means we can't differentiate between what was left incomplete is what you don't understand. The `default` case is what would lose sending data, but that is obviously wrong (jut like the extra goroutines, or unused waitgroup is obviously wrong), so we need context into why it's there in the first place.

Comment: @JimB i have understood it,and just i said earlier, thanks for your patience and your help. i tried to do my best and i was thinking that my issue was on the "socket side" of the program, but it wasn't.like chmike said, my problem was on the unbuffered channel. i just tried his solution and it works perfectly. now i will edit my question, trying to put a better code , thanks again

Comment: @JimB if you think that my new code is unclear please let me know , so i can edit it and improve my question, anyway thanks

Comment: @Leonardo, The new code is much clearer, though there are other still unrelated issues. Your handling of `Read` isn't correct, see [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/?tab=doc#Reader). It's also dubious that there is no message framing, since unix sockets are a stream, you could be getting multiple or partial messages in each read or write. You will also find that most servers will try hard to avoid allocating a new buffer for ever single read, but that means restructuring your program as a whole (though not much of a concern if reads are infrequent).

Comment: @JimB thanks for the advices :) . i moved the buffer creation outside of the for{} so, now the buffer is created only once.i will try the other suggestion too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem was in the function:

```
func sendDataToClient(data []byte, ch chan []byte) {
    select {
    case ch <- data:
        // if I put a little sleep here, no problems
        // if I remove the sleep, only data1 is sent to the client
        // time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    default:
}
```

If the channel `ch` isn't ready at the moment the function is called, the `default` case will be taken and the `data` will never be sent. In this case you should eliminate the function and send to the channel directly.

Buffering the channel is orthogonal to the problem at hand, and should be done for the similar reasons as you would buffered IO, i.e. provide a "buffer" for writes that can't immediately progress. If the code were not able progress without a buffer, adding one only delays possible deadlocks.

You also don't need the `exit` sentinel value here, as you could range over the channel and close it when you're done. This however still ignores write errors, but again that requires some re-design.

```
for data := range ch {
    c.Write(data)
}
```

You should also be careful passing slices over channels, as it's all too easy to lose track of which logical process has ownership and is going to modify the backing array. I can't say from the information given if passing the read+write data over channels improves the architecture, but this is not a pattern you will find in most go networking code.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i'm glad that u helped me , and i think i will review my architecture after this readings

Answer (score 0):

JimB gave a good explanation, so I think his answer is the better one.

I have included my partial solution in this answer.

I was thinking that my code was clear and simplified, but as Jim said I can do it simpler and clearer. I leave my old code posted so people can understand better how you can post simpler code and not do a mess like I did.

As chmike said, my issue wasn't related to the socket like I was thinking, but was only related to the channel. Write on a unbuffered channel was one of the problems. After change the unbuffered channel to a buffered one, the issue was resolved. Anyway, this code is not "good code" and can be improved following the principles that JimB has written in his answer.

So here is the new code:

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const socketName string = "./test_socket"

// create the socket and accept clients connections
func launchServerUDS(ch chan []byte, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    if err := os.RemoveAll(socketName); err != nil {
        return
    }
    l, err := net.Listen("unix", socketName)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer l.Close()
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        // this goroutine are launched when a client is connected
        // routine that listen and echo commands
        go commandsHandlerRoutine(conn, ch)
        // routine to send data read from the sensors to the client
        go autoSendRoutine(conn, ch)
    }
}

// routine that sends data to the client
func autoSendRoutine(c net.Conn, ch chan []byte) {
    for {
        data := <-ch
        if string(data) == "exit" {
            return
        }
        c.Write(data)
    }
}

// handle commands received from the client
func commandsHandlerRoutine(c net.Conn, ch chan []byte) {
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        n, err := c.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            // if i can't read send an exit command to autoSendRoutine and exit
            ch <- []byte("exit")
            break
        }
        // now, for sake of simplicity , only echo commands back to the client
        _, err = c.Write(buf[:n])
        if err != nil {
            // if i can't write back send an exit command to autoSendRoutine and exit
            ch <- []byte("exit")
            break
        }
    }
}

// this goroutine reads from the sensors and write to the channel , so data are sent
// to the client if a client is connected
func dummyReadDataRoutine(ch chan []byte, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    x := 0
    for x < 100 {
        // read data from the sensors every 5 seconds
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        // read first data and send it
        ch <- []byte("data1\n")
        // read second data and send it
        ch <- []byte("data2\n")
        // read third data and send it
        ch <- []byte("data3\n")
        x++
    }
    wg.Done()
}


func main() {
    // create a BUFFERED CHANNEL
    ch := make(chan []byte, 1)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)
    // launch the goruotines that handle the socket connections
    // and read data from the sensors
    go dummyReadDataRoutine(ch, &wg)
    go launchServerUDS(ch, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: The problem wasn't the unbuffered channel, the problem was the `default` in the `select` which caused you to drop attempts to write to the channel when it wasn't immediately ready.

Comment: @halfer i hope now is ok, i'm sorry for this mess guys, thanks for all the help